# angular2 two-way-binding of array-type to single value

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm using a child component to select values which should be updated in my model. The child component accepts an `Array<string>` via `@Input()` if I pass in property from my model which is an `Array<string>` itself everything works as expected an when a value is selected in the child, the model gets updated.

However as an additional requirement I also need to pass in a single-valued (i.e. a regular `string`, so non-array) property of my model and whenever the user selects a value in the child I'd like to update my single-value model property immediately.

I tried creating the array from the template using `[(selectedValues)]=[parentSingleValue]` but this fails with

> Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 20 in
>   [[parentSingleValue]=$event]

I created a plunkr to illustrate the issue. Click the items to test it: https://plnkr.co/edit/bHCAaycwZLOddry0gOU7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong here

1. You don't need the `[(selectedValues)]="parentValues"` syntax, because there is nothing going from the child to the parent -
   `[selectedValues]="parentValues"` will work the same.
2. It only works because you are passing an array and modifying the array inside the child, so - by side effect. Pass it a copy of the array and it will cease to work.
3. Your `@Output() eventEmitter` is unused. It would be used if you did something like `[selectedValues]="parentValues" (eventEmitter)="someEventHandlingMethod()"`

A solution to what you are trying to achieve would be to simply remove the `@Input()` parameter, and change the `@Output()` one to emit a simple string, then in the parent handle it by pushing it into the array and setting the single value at the same time.

Child:

```
@Output()
onItemSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();

...

public addValue(value: string) {
  this.onItemSelected.emit(value);
}
```

Parent:

```
export class App {
  parentValues: Array<string> = [];
  parentSingleValue = '';

  itemSelected(item: string) {
    this.parentValues.push(item);
    this.parentSingleValue = item;
  }
}
```

Parent template:

```
<h1>Simply:</h1>
<app-child (onItemSelected)="itemSelected($event)"></app-child>

Single value: {{parentSingleValue}}<br>

<div *ngFor="let value of parentValues">
  <p>{{value}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine, the reason is you assigned an empty string.

[See modified one](https://plnkr.co/edit/n8BPGBal6rICKsKqgZam?p=preview)

Alternatively,

```
<app-child [(selectedValues)]="parentValues"></app-child>
<div *ngFor="let value of parentValues">
  <p>{{value}}</p>
</div>

<h1>With singleValue:</h1>
<app-child [selectedValues]="converToArray(parentSingleValue)"></app-child>
<div>
  <p>{{parentSingleValue}}</p>
</div>


export class App {
  title = 'app works!';
  parentValues: Array<string> = [];
  parentSingleValue = '212121';
  converToArray(s:string){
    let temp= new Array();
    temp.push(s);
    return temp

  }
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mUTF7GUja6rraGyKal4K?p=preview)**

Comment: neither with the plunkr nor your alternative the parentSingleValue gets updated when an item is clicked in the child. THat's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: where you are updating ??